# General mapping of a ring homomorphism from ZxZ to ZxZ

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

Suppose we have $\phi : \mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$ , where $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism. Also, assume we know $\phi(1,0) = (a,b)$ and $\phi(0,1) = (c,d)$. Then suppose we want to know the mapping of some other $(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$.

In general, will $\phi(m,n) = m\cdot(a,b) + n\cdot(c,d)$ ?

My reasoning here is the following:

$\phi(m,n) = \phi(m\cdot(1,0)+n\cdot(0,1))$. Then, since $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism, this is equal to $\phi(m\cdot(1,0)) + \phi(n\cdot(0,1))$, and since $m$ and $n$ and simply constants, this equals $m\cdot\phi(1,0) + n\cdot\phi(0,1)$ = $m\cdot(a,b) + n\cdot(c,d)$.

Does this logic check out? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "since that $m$ and $n$ are simply constants" has nothing to do with ring homomorphism.

Comment: What I meant by $m\cdot(1,0)$ was $(1,0)+(1,0)+...+(1,0)$ $m$ many times. Which would simplify to the way which I wrote above. Since the binary operations involved are just normal addition and multiplication of each element.

Comment: Ok, that's much better. Well, this shows that you understood things properly. Good job.

Comment: Note that you never actually used the ring structure or the multiplicative property of a ring homomorphism here, just the Abelian group structure. In other words, since $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is a free Abelian group on two generators, any group homomorphism out of it is entirely determined by its values on the two generators $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Alex That makes sense, but are you saying that there is a simpler way to go about it where I can take advantage of the ring structure?

Comment: I am more of the opinion that the ring structure is irrelevant, or even detrimental, to your main question (which is fundamentally about mappings out of free objects). Products of rings are **not** free, and in fact are quite poorly behaved. Note for instance that if you require $\phi$ to be a ring homomorphism, then you force the stringent relations $(0,0) = \phi(0,0) = \phi((1,0)(0,1)) = (a,b)(c,d) = (ac,bd)$, meaning that either $a$ or $c$ and either $b$ or $d$ have to be a zero divisor. In this case, zero divisor = $0$.

Comment: Moreover, most authors nowadays require ring homomorphisms to preserve the multiplicative identity, which means in this case the additional requirement $(1,1) = \phi(1,1) = \phi((1,0) + (0,1)) = (a,b) + (c,d) = (a+c,b+d)$. If we combine both restrictions, we get only four possibilities for $\phi$...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have $\phi : \mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$ , where $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism. Then it must satisfy the following 2 conditions:

for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$

1. $\phi (a+b) =\phi (a) + \phi (b)$
2. $\phi (a\cdot b) =\phi (a)\cdot\phi (b)$

Then for $(1,0) \in \mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$, we know that $(1,0)\cdot(1,0)=(1,0)$, so $$\phi((1,0))=\phi ((1,0)\cdot(1,0)) =\phi ((1,0)) \cdot\phi ((1,0)) =\phi ((1,0))^2$$
Under what condition does $\phi ((1,0))^2 = \phi((1,0))$?

Suppose $\phi((1,0)) = (a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$, then $a^2 = a$ and $b^2 = b$. Solving it gives you $a=1$ or $0$, $b=1$ or $0$.

We know $\phi$ must map $(0,0)$ to $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ to $(1,1)$. So the only options for $\phi((1,0))$ would be $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$.